# IIB: Passing local variable to ESQL select statement

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I need to retrieve datas from two tables based on the Job code which is given in the input xml in IIB/WMB.

SQL Query

```
SELECT D.DEPTNO,D.DNAME,D.LOC,E.EMPNO,E.ENAME,E.JOB,E.SAL FROM DEPT D JOIN EMP E on E.JOB ='MANAGER' OR E.JOB = 'CLERK'
```

ESQL Query

Getting the JOB details from input xml and assigning it to local variable.

```
SET type1 = InputRoot.XMLNSC.Employee.Type[1];
SET type2 = InputRoot.XMLNSC.Employee.Type[2];
```

Now I need to pass the above variables to my ESQL query.

```
SET Outputroot.XMLNSC.List[] = PASSTHRU('SELECT D.DEPTNO,D.DNAME,D.LOC,E.EMPNO,E.ENAME,E.JOB,E.SAL FROM Database.EMP AS E,Database.DEPT AS D where E.JOB =?' VALUES('type1','type2')) ;
```

But the above query is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in this query:

First, you are passing two parameters but only one question mark (?) exists in the query.

Second, you are passing a string value like 'type1' and the correct is to pass the variable:

```
SET Outputroot.XMLNSC.List[] = PASSTHRU('SELECT D.DEPTNO,D.DNAME,D.LOC,E.EMPNO,E.ENAME,E.JOB,E.SAL FROM Database.EMP AS E,Database.DEPT AS D where E.JOB =?' VALUES(type1)) ;
```

Comment: Thanks rafael. But the above query is also not working. I am getting the following exception "SQL command not properly ended".

Comment: You don't need the Database keyword in front of your table names in a PASSTHRU. And by the way do you really want a cartesian join here? It doesn't seem too practical given the names of your tables and columns. And while we are at it, why do you need a PASSTHRU even? Your query should work in a esql select too.

Comment: Attila is rigth. Database must be passed in passthru query. Database must be use only in the native SELECT ESQL sintax.

Comment: thank you for your inputs. You guys were right, database keyword should not be used in passthru statement.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
    DECLARE designation char;
       DECLARE designation1 char;
       DECLARE Query char;



      FOR source AS InputRoot.XMLNSC.Employees.Designation[]  DO
                IF(source = '') THEN
                    SET designation = 'Empty';
                ELSE        
                    SET designation = designation1 ||''''||UPPER(source)||'''';                     
                SET designation1 = ''''||UPPER(source)||''''||','||designation1 ;

            END IF;      


SET Query = '(SELECT D.DEPTNO,D.DNAME,D.LOC,E.EMPNO,E.ENAME,E.JOB,E.SAL FROM EMP AS E JOIN DEPT AS D on D.DEPTNO = E.DEPTNO where E.JOB in ('||designation||'))';

SET Outputroot.XMLNSC.List[] = PASSTHRU(Query);
```

Comment: I know that the statements for creating designation(CLERK,MANAGER) were redundant. I need advice on that part.

Answer (score 0):

Add `To Database.DBName` after your PASSTHRU statement where DBName is your database name

Like this:

```
SET Outputroot.XMLNSC.List[] = PASSTHRU('SELECT D.DEPTNO,D.DNAME,D.LOC,E.EMPNO,E.ENAME,E.JOB,E.SAL FROM Database.EMP AS E,Database.DEPT AS D where E.JOB =?' VALUES(type1)) To Database.DBName ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The passthru call should be

```
SET Outputroot.XMLNSC.List[] = PASSTHRU('SELECT D.DEPTNO,D.DNAME,D.LOC,E.EMPNO,E.ENAME,E.JOB,E.SAL FROM Database.EMP AS E,Database.DEPT AS D where E.JOB in (? , ?)', type1,type2) ;
```

OR

```
SET Outputroot.XMLNSC.List[] = PASSTHRU('SELECT D.DEPTNO,D.DNAME,D.LOC,E.EMPNO,E.ENAME,E.JOB,E.SAL FROM Database.EMP AS E,Database.DEPT AS D where E.JOB=? or E.JOB=?)', type1,type2) ;
```