# IIB v10: Passing local variable to ESQL select statement

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I am new to IIB, trying to connect to Oracle DB using ESQL. Trying to pass a local param to where clause in simple SELECT statement. Getting below error while executing it. Can anyone help me out

```
ESQL:
    BROKER SCHEMA com.project


CREATE COMPUTE MODULE MainFlow_Compute
    CREATE FUNCTION Main() RETURNS BOOLEAN
    BEGIN
        DECLARE var REFERENCE TO Environment.Variables;
        DECLARE username CHAR;

        SET username = InputRoot.JSON.Data.userid;

        --SET OutputRoot.XML.Invoice[] = SELECT E.EMPLOYEE_ID,E.FIRST_NAME FROM Database.HR.EMPLOYEES AS E WHERE E.EMPLOYEE_ID=username;
        SET OutputRoot.XML.Invoice[] = PASSTHRU('SELECT E.EMPLOYEE_ID,E.FIRST_NAME FROM Database.HR.EMPLOYEES AS E WHERE E.EMPLOYEE_ID=?' VALUES(username));
        SET OutputRoot.JSON.Data.user_id=username;
        --SET OutputRoot.JSON.Data.user_name=var.profile.FIRST_NAME;        

        RETURN TRUE;
    END;
END MODULE;
```

Log:

> ```
> Error: BIP3113E: Exception detected in message flow com.project.MainFlow
>          http://localhost:7800/users/getUserDetails
>          Exception. BIP2230E: Error detected whilst processing a message in node 'com.project.MainFlow.Compute'. : F:\build\slot2\S1000_P\src\DataFlowEngine\SQLNodeLibrary\ImbComputeNode.cpp: 515: ImbComputeNode::evaluate: ComIbmComputeNode: com/project/MainFlow#FCMComposite_1_4
> BIP2488E:  ('com.project.MainFlow_Compute.Main', '14.4') Error detected while executing the SQL statement ''SET OutputRoot.XML.Invoice[] = DEFAULTPASSTHRU('SELECT E.EMPLOYEE_ID,E.FIRST_NAME FROM Database.HR.EMPLOYEES AS E WHERE E.EMPLOYEE_ID=?', username);''. : F:\build\slot2\S1000_P\src\DataFlowEngine\ImbRdl\ImbRdlStatementGroup.cpp: 767: SqlStatementGroup::execute: : 
> BIP2321E: Database error: ODBC return code '-1' using ODBC driver manager ''odbc32.dll''. : F:\build\slot2\S1000_P\src\DataFlowEngine\MessageServices\ImbOdbc.cpp: 3814: ImbOdbcStatement::checkRcInner: : 
> BIP2322E: Database error: SQL State ''IM001''; Native Error Code '0'; Error Text ''[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver does not support this function''. : F:\build\slot2\S1000_P\src\DataFlowEngine\MessageServices\ImbOdbc.cpp: 4035: ImbOdbcStatement::checkRcInner: :
> ```

Note: I have referred to below link already

[IIB: Passing local variable to ESQL select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43114965/iib-passing-local-variable-to-esql-select-statement)

Comment: Ok so your error is BIP2322E note that Exceptions stack and it's the last one that tells you what's gone wrong, on some occasions the second last exception may give you additional context.

Comment: If you do a search of Google using BIP2322 note I dropped the last character this seems to make searches work a bit better, I don't know why as Google. Then should find a link for "BIP2000-2999: Runtime components - Broker - IBM" open that and search for BIP2322 and read it. One of the recommendations is to try mqsicvp for the connection so try mqsicvp <YourBrokerName> -n <ODBCName>

Comment: Thanks for your reply @TJA, Statement is executing and fetching the data from DB if I pass static value like E.EMPLOYEE_ID = 100. But getting this error while passing only parameter like E>EMPLOYEE_ID=userid. I have tried using PASSTHRU also. 

I have tried mqsicvp TESTNODE_USER -n ROUTING

It shows as below::


BIP8270I: Connected to Datasource 'ROUTING' as user 'SYSTEM'. The datasource platform is 'Oracle', version '11.02.0000 Oracle 11.2.0.1.0'.

Comment: So is that literally E.EMPLOYEE_ID = 100 not E.EMPLOYEE_ID = '100' maybe it's some kind of value conversion. Is the column CHAR or some kind of NUMBER? You could try VALUES(CAST username AS INTEGER). Or if you want to wade through 1MB of text or so then do a trace mqsichangetrace, mqsireadlog, mqsiformatlog. Start with -u for a user trace and -l debug and -r for reset. I'm always reluctant to do the mqsichangetrace thing but often end up wondering why. Best of luck.

Comment: So you already tried to do it without the PASSTHRU and the '?' ? Because I've never seen this synthax for an odbc connction (I usually do it with java, I've never tried with ESQL to be honest)